# C# Bot framework: How to set a field optional in the form flow Dialog

Tags: c#, botframework

I am trying to build a bot which have a form flow dialog in it. I have to make a field in my form builder to `Optional`. I done by giving the `[Optional]` annotation in my class attribute. But its not working. By Form keeps prompting for the field. How can i control this?

```
form = new FormBuilder<myClass>()
                    .Message("Welcome")
                    .Field(nameof(xxx))
                    .Field(nameof(yyy),//make this field optional, if value is there then validate. But should not prompt if no value.                        
                        validate: async (state, value) =>
                        {
                        }
```

My Class

```
[Serializable]
public class myClass
{
    [Prompt("I didnt get you")]       
    public string xxx{ get; set; }

    [Optional]       
    public string yyy{ get; set; }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
[Optional] 
public string yyy{ get; set; }
```

Comment: getting error "The type 'string' must be a non-nullable value type in order to use it as parameter 'T' in the generic type or method 'Nullable<T>"

Answer (score 0):

In official documentation the Custom Attribute [Optional] is used only for nullable enums Properties... In this case, it shows a last option tagged as "No Preference".

For strings the default prompt will show your question followed by "(current choice: No Preference) showing that it was filled with the default value "No Preference" but the user still need to answer the question.

If you need to skip the question based on a specific rule you can implement the active property like in example below:

```
  public static IForm<YourStateClass> Build()
  {
     return new FormBuilder<SandwichOrder>()
     .Field(nameof(PropertyName), active: (state) => { 
          // here goes your code that need to return a boolean where true will show the field and false will skip 
      })
     .Build();
  }
```